# Laravel Passport without oAuth

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-6

I want to use laravel passport to secure my api calls. But I don't want to use access_tokens which are connected to users.

I'd like create a client (`artisan passport:client`) and use the ID and secret to authorize my requests. I just can't figure out how it should work or if it's even possible.
Does someone know how to achieve this?

I want to make the API calls using guzzle in php.

Comment: You want to secure the calls of your frontend JavaScript or your other apps?

Comment: Calls will be made in PHP using guzzle

Comment: Out of curiosity: if your tokens are not connected to any user, what's the point of using tokens? How do you want to handle permissions then?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I want to make sure that not everyone can make requests to the api. By using tokens I make sure that you really need to know a key and a secret before you can make the call.

Comment: And how do you distinguish different access levels? How do you know which token was granted for which user if you don't want to use user entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm you could make use of Passport's [Client Credentials Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens). From the docs:

> ### Client Credentials Grant Tokens
>
> The client credentials grant is suitable for machine-to-machine
>   authentication. For example, you might use this grant in a scheduled
>   job which is performing maintenance tasks over an API.
>
> Before your application can issue tokens via the client credentials
>   grant, you will need to create a client credentials grant client. You
>   may do this using the `--client` option of the `passport:client`
>   command:
>
> ```
> php artisan passport:client --client
> ```
>
> Next, to use this grant type, you need to add the
>   `CheckClientCredentials` middleware to the `$routeMiddleware` property
>   of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:
>
> ```
> use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials;
>
> protected $routeMiddleware = [
>     'client' => CheckClientCredentials::class,
> ];
> ```
>
> Then, attach the middleware to a route:
>
> ```
> Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
>     ...
> })->middleware('client');
> ```
>
> To restrict access to the route to specific scopes you may provide a
>   comma-delimited list of the required scopes when attaching the
>   `client` middleware to the route:
>
> ```
> Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
>     ...
> })->middleware('client:check-status,your-scope');
> ```
>
> #### Retrieving Tokens
>
> To retrieve a token using this grant type, make a request to the
>   `oauth/token` endpoint:
>
> ```
> $guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
>
> $response = $guzzle->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
>     'form_params' => [
>         'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
>         'client_id' => 'client-id',
>         'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
>         'scope' => 'your-scope',
>     ],
> ]);
>
> return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['access_token'];
> ```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, but I get this message when requesting the token:
`{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}`. I do send all the parameters just as in your example using postman.

Comment: sorry, somehow I get an error in postman, but it does work when I use in with Guzzle.

Comment: Glad to help :) Btw, it should work in postman too. That's weird, but at least you make it work.

Comment: Yeah I think I missed some headers there